# How to configure IntelliJ IDEA to load license server address from a properties file?

Tags: intellij-idea, configuration, license-key

My goal is to avoid manual configuration of the license server:

```
Help > Register > IntelliJ IDEA License Activation Dialog is opened > License server
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked the same question on the IntelliJ IDEA Help Center and got an answer from JetBrains support employee: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206666999

Seems that there is no IntelliJ configuration property to setup the license server.

The options are either to configure the [DNS lookup](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/license_server/configure_automatic_server_discovery.html) or to copy an existing key into the config folder.

Answer (score 5):

There is actually a simple way, contrary to the accepted answer. It is just a matter of creating this file (on macOS):

`$HOME/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea<version>/idea.key`

That path will need to be adjusted for Windows and Linux.

The contents of this file is just a single line pointing to your license server. For example, if your license server is running at `http://jetbrains.example.com`, then the `idea.key` file should contain:

`URL:http://jetbrains.example.com`